# .netCore How to pass data to controller from table of list?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I hava a list of objects in my view. In a table, with some conditions I create rows and add a button. I want to pass that row's data to my controller when button of modal-footer is pressed. I tried ajax request and forms but I could not manage that up. What is coming to my controller is always the first element of list.

My view:

```
<table class="table border-bottom dataTable" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr><th rowspan="1">Saat</th><th rowspan="1">Durum</th></tr>
            </thead>
            @{int i = 0; }
            @foreach (var v in Model)
            {
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        @if (v.IsActive == 1)
                        {
                            <td>@v.Hour.ToString():@v.Minute.ToString().ElementAt(0)0</td>
                            <td><p class="blckpassive">Dolu</p></td>                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@v.Hour.ToString():@v.Minute.ToString().ElementAt(0)0</td>
                            <td><p class="blckactive">Boş</p></td>                                                                                  
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Randevu Al</button></td>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Emin Misiniz?</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            Seçtiğiniz Randevuyu Almak İstiyor Musunuz?
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>
                                            <a type="button" href="/Appointment/AddAppointment?hour=@v.Hour" class="btn btn-primary">Evet</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                i++; 
                
            }

        </table>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult AddAppointment(int hour)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Objects in list has hour and minute variables which are int and sorted as "9:00,9:30,10:00,10:30...16:00".

Comment: `v.Hour` is the first item in that list?

Or do you mean that each `v` in `Model` has a different `.Hour` of 9, 9:30, 10...

Comment: Also does the table show the correct times and it is only broken on, licking the link?

Comment: @MenachemHornbacher Table showing correct data, each v in model has a different hour, yes.

Comment: Interesting, what are the links in the list. do they all have the same value or it is only on submission that that occurs?

Comment: @MenachemHornbacher They all have different values, coming from db. On submission I need to know which value is clicked so I need data from that object. I will fill db with it also.

Comment: Could you share your full code so that it can be reproduced well, additionally share your model as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is coming to my controller is always the first element of list.

You put the code of popup modal dialog in a foreach loop, if you check the html source code, you can find that multiple button(s) with same value `#exampleModal` of `data-target` attribute, and target modal(s) with same value `exampleModal` of `id` attribute, which cause the above issue.

To resolve this issue and make modal popup works well, you can modify the code as below to make the `data-target` attribute of button trigger and `id` attribute of modal **unique** within the HTML document.

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target=@("#exampleModal"+i)>Randevu Al</button></td>
<div class="modal fade" id=@("exampleModal"+i) tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: I see, always need unique ids. Thanks a lot!